# Setting up Oracle 19c Database instance with access from different subnets using scan listeners

Tags: oracle, listener, rac

We have a RAC cluster where we are upgrading a database. (12c to 19c) The upgrade process is to build a new database on the same cluster and import a copy of the old database.

The old database has a scan listener setup where it can be connected to on a different subnet than the default. As a matter of fact, the old database is available on the default subnet as well as the special subnet.

Since I am just adding a new database to the cluster, I am confident that the network and VIPs are correctly setup and I should be able to just simply add the new database and configure the local_listener parameter in the database.

Since the old database is setup with the proper scan listener and network, I would have thought that adding the parameter in the database would be all that was needed.

In an effort to add the special subnet (scan listener) to the database, I have ran an alter system to set each database’s local_listener parameter.

```
Node1:
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orarac1a-vip)(PORT=1521))' scope=both sid='oranode1';

Node2:
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=orarac2a-vip)(PORT=1521))' scope=both sid='oranode2';
```

Then on each database I have ran “alter system register;” and restarted each of the new database instances. I have also reloaded the listener as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fix: I just needed to add a remote listener parameter to the database.

```
alter system set remote_listener='prodorarac02-scan:1521' scope=both sid='*';
```

Then:

```
alter system register;
```

After that, I can access the instance on both the default listener as well as the remote listener.
I really struggled with this one. After finding the fix, I realize that it was simple, and any real DBA would know the answer. Because I was not able to find much information on this, I wanted to share in case it helps the next person.

It is just a matter of adding a remote_listener. The database needs to have this remote_listener setup so that he registers with the proper listener. In RAC this name will be a DNS name with usually 2-4 IP addresses that can be accessed. They get accessed either round-robin or based on how they load balance. In my case, all of that was already setup and all we are doing is adding a new database instance.
Here are some helpful things to look at if you have other systems to compare.

```
show parameter local_listener -- shows the address for the local listener - likely null. 
show parameter service_names -- will show the service names and if someone had an alias for the DB.
show parameter remote_listener -- will show the address for the remote listener.
```